# Add search textfield in tableview programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitableview

[image]

[image]

I used storyboard to build the tableview with the search textfield in the ViewController, when i drag textfield on position and it work well. But when i tried without storyboard and add textfield in tableview it cover on first cell. And when i use section header it will stay on fix position.

```
tableview.addsubview (textfield)
```

textfield will cover on first cell on the tableView

appreciate for any reply

Comment: add it to the tableViews header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add default searchBar to `UITableView`, like this

```
UISearchBar *testbar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 44)];;
[[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:testbar];
```

Or you can create first cell with textfield and pass data from cell to controller by your custom delegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)loadTableView {

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar; 

}
```

Comment: are u still facing issue..?

Answer (score 0):

var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

self.resultSearchController = ({

```
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 70/255,green: 70/255,blue: 71/255, alpha:0.9)
        let textField = controller.searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as! UITextField
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 16/255,green: 16/255,blue: 16/255, alpha:0.3)
        controller.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        Segtable.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
        controller.definesPresentationContext = true
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self
        controller.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        return controller

    })()
```

Below are the delegate methods

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
    {
}

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, learned a lot of UISearchController